# Limit of 2 functions equal to 0 at x equal to zero

Tags: calculus, limits

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are differentiable such that $f(0)=g(0)=0 $ and $g'(0)\neq 0$, find the limit as $x\to 0$ of
$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ in terms of $f(x), g(x) $ and $g'(x)$ (Note: You may not use L'Hospital's Rule).

Any help with this question is massively appreciated, I have absolutely no idea where even to start with it. Thanks!

Comment: If we know $f'(0)$, then we can sort of cheat and use the definition of the derivative.

Comment: If $f(x) = \lambda g(x)$ then the limit is $\lambda$. Thus, you won't be able to express the limit in terms of $f(0)$,$g(0)$,$g'(0)$, since how would that produce $\lambda$? I'm unsure what exactly the question means by "in terms of $f(x)$, $g(x)$ and $g'(x)$" - due to the above, I'm fairly certain you can't state this limit without using a, well, limit, or without more knowledge about the functions involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{g(x) - g(0)} $$

(Because $f(0) = g(0) = 0$)

$$ = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$$ for $c \in (0, x)$ (Cauchy's theorem)

$$ = \lim_{c \to 0} \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)} = \frac{f'(0)}{g'(0)}$$

Since $f'$ and $g'$ exists and $g' \neq 0$

Comment: If you divide out by $x=x-0$, you don't even need Cauchy's theorem:$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}}{\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}}=\frac{f'(0)}{g'(0)}.$$

Comment: true! Thanks ;)

Comment: Wow I can't thank any of you enough- this has been causing me untold misery!

Comment: @Gabriel if you've liked the answer please accept it (there is a little check below the vote count ;-) )